# Likebox and language

Tags: facebook-likebox

i am using following code to display the likebox. My website is in different languages, so i would like to display this in other languages than english. All options i found on internet seem to have disappeared with the latest facebook version.

`div class="fb-like-box" data-href=... data-width="200" data-height="300" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"`

So is there a language parameter to add to this ? If not, what other option do i have ?

Answer (score 3):

You can switch language with this js code

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

and here, the language is `en_US`.

You have more choices languages on this link : https://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml

Comment: thanks. unfortunately, although i am able to handle html, i have no clue how to include java inside my html code !!

Comment: put this line in script balise in the head of your html page.